# Connect to Azure Sql server using 443 port

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have an Azure sql database, the problem is our office firewall doesn't allow to access port 1433 however we have access to some other ports like 443 and 80. is it a way to change the Azure sql ports or use other Azure services like Load Balancer or Application Gateway to redirect the ports from 443 to 1433?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try NAT port-forwarding rule [Reference URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal). We have used for other port I never tried 443 to 1443.

Comment: thanks, i've manged to get it working using Azure Load balancer and NAT port-forwarding

Comment: @mohsen, if you are using azure LB, how do you target Azure SQL database service as the backend?

Comment: @NancyXiong, my database was actualy on an Azure VM and not Azure Sql database service.

Comment: well, this makes sense. If Azure SQL database service, you could not use Azure LB.